# Why does adding '1' to a variable in javascript add '3'

Tags: javascript, html

I've just made two simple functions which I linked to the onClick property of two buttons on a HTML page.

One function looks up the width of a div and then it should just add '1', but instead it adds '3'. The other function looks up the width of a div and then it should subtract '1'. Instead of doing that, it adds '1'

Could someone enlighten me why this happens and show me to correct this?

```
function bigger() {
    var div_kubus = document.getElementById('kubus');
    var x = div_kubus.offsetWidth;
    var y = parseInt(x) + 1;
    var tekst = document.getElementById('tekst');
    tekst.value = y;
    div_kubus.style.width = y + 'px';
    /*div_kubus.setAttribute('style','width:'+y+'px');*/
}

function smaller() {
    var div_kubus = document.getElementById('kubus');
    var x = div_kubus.offsetWidth;
    var tekst = document.getElementById('tekst');
    x -= 1;
    div_kubus.setAttribute("style", "width:" + x + "px");
    tekst.value = x;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't. Fix your assertion: `x = 2; x = x + 1; alert(x)` (x is 3, just in case there was any doubt). I suspect that 2 is being added somewhere as `x + 1 + 2 = x + 3` and `x - 1 + 2 = x + 1`.

Comment: I think div_kubus.offsetWidth = 2 hence..

Comment: Just in case, I suggest you provide the second parameter in the parseInt function as 10 if you're using the decimal system, to avoid any unnecessary problems.

Comment: Use `console.log(x)` to see the value of `x` in your browser's console. You'll find it is not `1`.

Comment: No need to use `parseInt` on `div_kubus.offsetWidth` since `offsetWidth` already is a number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.offsetWidth` will return the width including borders and padding:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.offsetWidth

So I'm assuming that you've probably got a 1px border (or padding) that is adding 2 to your expected width (1px for the left, 1px for the right). Therefore, adding 1, adds 3; and subtracting 1, adds 1.

Comment: I still don't quite get it, but your logic makes sense. 
FYI padding and margin is set to zero.

The real problem is, I think, I'm reading out the offsetWidth and afterwards writing to style.width. Following your logic there's a 2px difference between those two.